# Vue router: anchor links to a specific place in a page e.g. /route/#anchor

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

Is there an established way to use vue-router (router-link) to link to a specific route, **including** an anchor on a page?

I can do this: `<router-link to="/page/#section">` and the router will work as expected, but only if I am on the actual /page/ location – it will scroll to the nearest element with id="section"

But if I use the same `router-link` from elsewhere (eg. /page2/) the router will return 404, because it will treat the `/#section` part as a nested route.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1.
Install `vue-scrollto`:

```
npm install --save vue-scrollto
```

2.
Setup `main.js`:

```
import VueScrollTo from 'vue-scrollto'
Vue.use(VueScrollTo)
```

3.
Set anchor ids (most likely in your `Home.vue`):

```
<template>
    <v-content>
      <SectionOne id="section-one"/>
      <SectionTwo id="section-two"/>
      <SectionThree id="section-three"/>
    </v-content>
</template>
```

4.
Link to anchor via `href` or `router-link`:

via `href`:

```
<a href="#" v-scroll-to="'#section-one'">
    Scroll to #section-one
</a>
```

via `router-link`:

```
<router-link to="#" v-scroll-to="'#section-two'">
    Scroll to #section-two
</router-link>
```

Comment: I don't see how this solves the OP's question. v-scroll-to seems to work on the current page only. I tried it in router-links to different pages and it didn't scroll

Comment: How could you solve this of router links to different pages, I am on page 2 and I use router-link but it does not send me to the section that I have defined with v-scroll-to. Could he really solve it and how?

Comment: @JG_GJ see my anser below. It works well

Answer (score 7):

Here is a solution for router links pointing to an anchor on a different page:

Use this link syntax: `<router-link to="/page#section">`. On the target page you need add your own scroll logic:

```js
        mounted() {
            var section=this.$router.currentRoute.value.hash.replace("#", "");
            if (section)
                this.$nextTick(()=> window.document.getElementById(section).scrollIntoView());
        },
```

This works quite well but you might want to add a bit of error handling for non-existent anchors.

Answer (score 2):

There's an example in the vue-router docs where they simulate the "scroll to anchor" behaviour: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/scroll-behavior.html

Example they link to near the bottom of the page:
https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/blob/dev/examples/scroll-behavior/app.js

I haven't tried it myself (yet), but appears to work for them.